# QUnit - test in loop, index always the same

Tags: javascript, jquery, qunit

I am trying to test some code and for that I need to make some tests in loop, like this:

```
for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
    QUnit.test('Hello ' + i, (assert) => {
        console.log(i);
        assert.ok( 1 == '1', 'Result: ' + i);
    });
}
```

[Click here for working example at jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vj2qk6rd/1/)

But for some reason `i` in the loop (and result) is always `6`, so this code gives me output like this:

```
6
6
6
6
6
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given that QUnit defines all tests prior to running them, you're a victim of the classic problem of `var` scope - `var`s are bound to the function, not to the `for` loop.

**What this means is:**
You define your test with a given value for `i`, but this value will have changed when the test is actually running.

You have a few ways around this:

#### Create an [IIFE](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/) and define your test inside it

```
for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
    (function (j) {
        QUnit.test('Hello ' + j, (assert) => {
            console.log(j);
            assert.ok( 1 == '1', 'Result: ' + j);
        });
    })(i);
}
```

**Why this works:** the `j` variable above will be bound to the scope of that IIFE. Its value will not change when the test is run.

#### Use `let` keyword in an ES6 environment

```
for (let i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
    QUnit.test('Hello ' + i, (assert) => {
        console.log(i);
        assert.ok( 1 == '1', 'Result: ' + i);
    });
}
```

**Why this works:** [ES6 finally introduces block scoping](http://www.2ality.com/2015/02/es6-scoping.html), but this is done via the keywords `let` or `const`.

<sub>some parts of this answer corroborated from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/750506/2083599)</sub>